# What is the equation for calculating AT LEAST x 6s on y rolls on a six sided dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

For example, If I rolled $6$ dice how likely is it that I get $1$ or more $6$s? I know how to do exact binomial distribution but I'm not sure how to do figure out this situation.

Comment: Add up the answer for exactly $x, x+1,\dots, y$

Comment: Could you please add some more context. What have you tried so far? How would you do if the question would be exactly *one* $6$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Try to figure out what is the *complement event*. (This is best only for the case for the question in the body of your post)

For the general case look at saulspatz comment under your question.